# Magento - Display Error/Notice on Login Page

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am writing a module to deny admin users access unless coming from a specific IP. I am hooking into the admin successful login event, checking their IP against an array of IPs and if the admin user's IP is not in the list I am logging them out, and redirecting them back to the admin login page.

My question is....

how do I set a message on the login page similar to "Incorrect Password"?

Any snippets or ideas are greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Jeff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to throw an exception like this:

```
Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('You are not authorized.'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Magento code does the following to display the "Invalid User Name or Password" message after an invalid login attempt. I would do the same then redirect back to the login page.

```
$message = "Whatever you want the user to see.";
Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($messages);
```